# Expected str instance, spacy.tokens.token.Token found

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am executing a data extraction use-case. To preprocess and tokenize my data, I am using both spacy English and German tokenizers, because the sentences are in both the languages. Here's my code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.de import German
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.lang.de import STOP_WORDS as stp_wrds_de
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as stp_wrds_en
import string

punctuations = string.punctuation

# German Parser
parser_de = German()
# English Parser
parser_en = English()

def spacy_tokenizer_de(document):
    # Token object for splitting text into 'units'
    tokens = parser_de(document)
    # Lemmatization: Grammatical conversion of words
    tokens = [word.lemma_.strip() if word.lemma_ != '-PRON-' else word for word in tokens]
    # Remove punctuations
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in punctuations]

    tokens_de_str = converttostr(tokens,' ')
    tokens_en = spacy_tokenizer_en(tokens_de_str)
    print("Tokens EN: {}".format(tokens_en))
    tokens_en = converttostr(tokens_en,' ')
    return tokens_en

def converttostr(input_seq, separator):
   # Join all the strings in list
   final_str = separator.join(input_seq)
   return final_str

def spacy_tokenizer_en(document):
    tokens = parser_en(document)
    tokens = [word.lemma_.strip() if word.lemma_ != '-PRON-' else word for word in tokens]
    return tokens
```

Here's a further elucidation of the above code:

**1. spacy_tokenizer_de():** Method to parse and tokenize document in German

**2. spacy_tokenizer_en():** Method to parse and tokenize document in English

**3. converttostr():** Converts list of tokens to a string, so that the English spacy tokenizer can read the input (only accepts document/string format) and tokenize the data.

However, some sentences when parsed, lead to the following error:
[image]

Why is a spacy token object coming up in such scenarios, whereas, some of the sentences are being processed successfully? Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 1):

`token.lemma_.strip() if token.lemma_ != '-PRON-' else token.text for token in tokens`

You're supposed to get a list of words here, right? Instead, sometimes you return a string (when lemma doesn't equal to '-PRON-') but other times just **token** but not a string.

You may get a string from `token.text`.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use proper names (token, not word). It's especially important in dynamically typed languages as Python so it's clear what data is behind.

Comment: Thank you @vitkarpov. Your suggestion worked! Also, I will keep in mind about your feedback regarding using proper names :)

Comment: @amlan.hackassin great! I'm happy to help :-) Take care!